# Localize the name of a plugin in the backend (registerPlugin)

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

With [registerPlugin](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_utility_1_1_extension_utility.html#a815dc76c1a5695b5e8949c5b71eaca8a) it is possible to define some parameter for a plugin in an extension.

```
ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    'Vendor' . $_EXTKEY,
    $pluginName,
    $backendTitle // <--- localize this !
);
```

I would like to know if it is possible to localize the third parameter, **plugin title**, so that the Backend User will see the correct language according to the language they are using.

The localization functions I looked at are usually directed at which language is selected in the frontend, e.g. [LocalizationUtility::translate](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/9-CrosscuttingConcerns/1-localizing-and-internationalizing-an-extension.html). Also, in the extensions I looked so far, they always use a static string, so I am not sure, if it is possible to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LLL in this form:

```
ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    'Vendor' . $_EXTKEY,
    'PluginName',
    'LLL:EXT:extkey/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:plugin_name'
);
```